# How many tuples $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ satisfied $1\le a_i\le 1000(i=\overline{1,n})$ and $GCD(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=5$.

Tags: combinatorics

How many tuples $(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ satisfied $1\le a_i\le 1000(i=\overline{1,n})$ and $GCD(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=5$.

This is my attemp: Let call $a_i=5b_i$. So we need count how many tuples $(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ satisfied $1\le b_i\le 200(i=\overline{1,n})$ and $GCD(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)=1$. But I can't go to the last solution !

Comment: I saw this recently on AoPS

Comment: I think you mean $1\le b_i\le 200$?

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I have edited ít!